# Change order of Javascript array according to math-based algorithm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a variable amount of boxes on a page, I am laying them out in a grid using CSS3 columns, I know I can use floats/inline-block/flexbox etc, but I *need* to use CSS3 columns for this layout.

The structure of the HTML is like:

```
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

With floats/inline-block etc, the visual order appears like so:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

With CSS columns, the visual order differs, like so:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

I can achieve my desired visual order by altering the HTML structure like so:

```
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

However, I can't do this manually all the time; what I want is to programatically reorder the HTML elements via Javascript which will adhere to the algorithm.

I've written a JS module which does the following:

- Reads the CSS `column-count` property and adds the number to a `data-cols` attribute of the main container
- Stores all box items in a variable
- Empties the container
- Creates an empty array
- Loops through each stored box item and gives it a `data-number` attribute - this is the index of each item
- Push the manipulated box HTML to the empty array
- Convert the array to HTML and insert it back into the container

So right now, the order doesn't change at all, but I figure it's a decent starting point.

I have a CodePen of this setup [here](http://codepen.io/tomblanchard/pen/PZLBMM).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edited version of you pen.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKxqmE?editors=1010

EDIT: Needed to return the results :p

You'll notice, I only did one thing. I pulled out the function that handles the ordering, and injected it in to the init method. Of course, this could be designed better, and you probably don't want the ordering method down in the resize method, but this was just to show the basic idea.

You want to separate the algorithm from the code that handles the result, that way you can inject in different ones as you please. A wonderful example of this is the native es5 filter function. Filter doesn't know how we want to handle things, so it let's us inject in our algorithm, and it just supplies us the items.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].filter(function(item) {
    return item > 3;
});
//=> [4,5]
```

I simply mimicked this by injecting your each function in the the init method, but you could inject any function. It accepts the items and does something to the result.

EDIT: I suggest watching this video by sandi metz. It's in ruby, but the same basic principles apply almost OOP languages. Specifically the bit at 36:00, when she talks about finding the roles in your algorithm, and then injecting the players of those roles. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lv2lBq6x4A

Comment: Yeah I did look into using `filter` but I'm not sure where to start, I checked out your pen and I get an `Uncaught TypeError: orderFn is not a function` error, I assume that's on purpose, but I'm struggling to grasp what I'm doing wrong, really appreciate your help though dude.

Comment: Nope, type error is because I didn't catch that you called init in two different places. Like I said, it should be designed a little better, such that there is a clean way (or, more descriptive, a better *place*) to inject things in. Right now I just did it the first place I could find, but I would recommend adjusting the design. Here's an updated pen!

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but you can use it as a reference: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/us0meufu/)

Comment: You'll notice I named the function 'defaultOrder' (taking cues from sandi). You can name the different 'algorithm' functions by how they order things. For example, one could *reverse* the order of the cells. You could also put these functions on an object and inject them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a snippet of what I ended up with.

It will "rejig" / change order of the elements so the layout goes from top to bottom from left to right (like traditional layout like floats). It also inserts empty items to account for the weirdness of CSS columns, the JS is flexible enough to work with any number of columns, it works off the `column-count` CSS property set to the `.masonry` element so it plays nice with media queries.

I intended to use this for masonry layouts but it turns out as soon as the elements vary in height, the order is thrown off completely, I have no idea how to fix this issue, it seems like a deal-breaker to me. If anyone wants to take a look, then feel free to have a play around.

```js
var Masonry = (function () {

  var _dom = {
    $root:  $('.js-masonry'),
    items:    '.js-masonry-item',
    $items: $('.js-masonry-item'),
    $empty: $('.js-masonry-empty')
  };

  var init = function () {
    _rejig();

    $(window).resize( function() { _rejig(); } );
  };

  var _rejig = function () {
    var colsCount  = parseInt( _dom.$root.css('column-count') );
    var itemsCount = _dom.$items.length;

    var emptyItem  = '<div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item js-masonry-empty"></div>';

    var html = [];

    _dom.$items.each(function( i, el ) {
      html.push( $(this).prop('outerHTML') );
    });

    if( itemsCount % colsCount !== 0 ) {
      var colPercentage = 100 / colsCount;
      var colThing = itemsCount * colPercentage;
      var colThingHighest = Math.ceil(colThing/100)*100;
      var colThing2 = colThingHighest - colThing;
      var colThing2 = Math.round( colThing2 / colPercentage );

      for ( var i = 0; i < colThing2; i++ ) {
        html.push( emptyItem );
      }
    } else {
      _dom.$empty.remove();
    }

    var newHtml = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < colsCount; i++ ) {
      for( var ii = i; ii < html.length; ii += colsCount ) {
        newHtml.push( html[ii] );
      }
    }

    var finalHtml = html;
    if( colsCount > 1 ) {
      finalHtml = newHtml;
    }
    finalHtml = finalHtml.join('');

    _dom.$root.html( finalHtml );
  };

  return {
    init: init
  };

})();

Masonry.init();
```

```css
.masonry {
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  column-count: 1;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 6;
    -moz-column-count: 6;
    column-count: 6;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 7;
    -moz-column-count: 7;
    column-count: 7;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 8;
    -moz-column-count: 8;
    column-count: 8;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 9;
    -moz-column-count: 9;
    column-count: 9;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 10;
    -moz-column-count: 10;
    column-count: 10;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 11;
    -moz-column-count: 11;
    column-count: 11;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
  .masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

.masonry-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}


.module {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}











* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(1) .module {
  background: #043a58;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(2) .module {
  background: #7b6840;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(3) .module {
  background: #73966b;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(4) .module {
  background: #e3846e;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(5) .module {
  background: #e55476;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(6) .module {
  background: #fc0b36;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(7) .module {
  background: #cf55fa;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(8) .module {
  background: #b63f2b;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(9) .module {
  background: #00f501;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(10) .module {
  background: #0cd914;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(11) .module {
  background: #e61139;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(12) .module {
  background: #819b14;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(13) .module {
  background: #728b2e;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(14) .module {
  background: #92bbfe;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(15) .module {
  background: #5025f0;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(16) .module {
  background: #70b665;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(17) .module {
  background: #3bed9b;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(18) .module {
  background: #9460d3;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(19) .module {
  background: #84c567;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(20) .module {
  background: #04c274;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(21) .module {
  background: #34cfe3;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(22) .module {
  background: #bea178;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(23) .module {
  background: #ea5b8c;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(24) .module {
  background: #63cc19;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(25) .module {
  background: #aca647;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(26) .module {
  background: #23d880;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(27) .module {
  background: #088935;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(28) .module {
  background: #17d978;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(29) .module {
  background: #577030;
}

.masonry-item:nth-of-type(30) .module {
  background: #465655;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry js-masonry">
  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      4
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      5
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      6
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      7
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      8
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      9
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      10
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      11
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      12
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      13
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      14
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      15
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      16
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      17
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      18
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      19
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      20
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      21
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      22
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      23
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      24
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      25
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-item js-masonry-item">
    <div class="module">
      26
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```